# Format of references slightly incorrect

Tags: cross-referencing, citing

I'm writing a proposal document and have to use the harvard referencing style for my citations. There, for the most part, has not been an issue with the standard authoryear syntax, however I have noticed that in papers with two authors, the first author's surname is properly formatted whereas the second is not. For example it would look like "Yan, Jeff and Brian Randell" instead of "Yan, J. and Randell, B.". Is there a way of changing this?

EDIT: Added a working example of what I mean

TeX section:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references}

\title{Example For TeX StackExchange}
\author{IBRice101}
\date{14/10/2022}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

This concern is, in fact, not unfounded. The kernel-level anti-cheat used in the popular role-playing game Genshin Impact, \texttt{mhyprot2.sys}, has been found to be used by ransomware actors in the wild to disable antivirus software prior to malware deployment (\cite{solivenRansomwareActorAbuses2022}).

\medskip

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

references.bib:

```
@online{solivenRansomwareActorAbuses2022,
  title = {Ransomware {{Actor Abuses Genshin Impact Anti-Cheat Driver}} to {{Kill Antivirus}}},
  author = {Soliven, Ryan and Kimura, Hitomi},
  date = {2022-08-24},
  url = {https://www.trendmicro.com/en_us/research/22/h/ransomware-actor-abuses-genshin-impact-anti-cheat-driver-to-kill-antivirus.html},
  urldate = {2022-10-01},
  abstract = {We investigate mhyprot2.sys, a vulnerable anti-cheat driver for the popular role-playing game Genshin Impact. The driver is currently being abused by a ransomware actor to kill antivirus processes and services for mass-deploying ransomware.},
  langid = {american},
  organization = {{Trend Micro}},
}
```

Comment: Please include a minimal working example in your question which allows people to reproduce your problem without having to guess which packages and bib style you might or might not use.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Adding  `giveninits=true` you get

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@online{solivenRansomwareActorAbuses2022,
    title = {Ransomware {{Actor Abuses Genshin Impact Anti-Cheat Driver}} to {{Kill Antivirus}}},
    author = {Soliven, Ryan and Kimura, Hitomi},
    date = {2022-08-24},
    url = {https://www.trendmicro.com/en_us/research/22/h/ransomware-actor-abuses-genshin-impact-anti-cheat-driver-to-kill-antivirus.html},
    urldate = {2022-10-01},
    abstract = {We investigate mhyprot2.sys, a vulnerable anti-cheat driver for the popular role-playing game Genshin Impact. The driver is currently being abused by a ransomware actor to kill antivirus processes and services for mass-deploying ransomware.},
    langid = {american},
    organization = {{Trend Micro}},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear, giveninits=true]{biblatex} % changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\title{Example For TeX StackExchange}
\author{IBRice101}
\date{14/10/2022}

\begin{document}
    
    \maketitle
    
    This concern is, in fact, not unfounded. The kernel-level anti-cheat used in the popular role-playing game Genshin Impact, \texttt{mhyprot2.sys}, has been found to be used by ransomware actors in the wild to disable antivirus software prior to malware deployment (\cite{solivenRansomwareActorAbuses2022}).
    
    \medskip        
    
    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```